# Java 8 Stream compare list of two objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I am looking for an example to filter two lists and create a list that contains only a subset based on condition. For example

- List-1 contains list of User objects
- List-2 contains list of PaidUser

Now I need to filter and prepare a list of unpaid users. Below code produce list with all elements but expectation is only "ABC" . Please assist

```
    class User {
        private String userName;
        private String age;

        public String getAge(){
            return age;
        }

        public String getUserName(){
            return userName;
        }

    }

    class PaidUser{
        private String userName;
        private double amt;

        public String getUserName(){
            return userName;
        }

    }

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    User u = new User();
    u.age = "12";
    u.userName = "XYZ";     
    users.add(u);
    u.age = "12";
    u.userName = "ABC";     
    users.add(u);

    List<PaidUser> paids = new ArrayList<>();
    PaidUser paid = new PaidUser();
    paid.userName = "XYZ";
    paid.amt = 1;
    paids.add(paid);


    List<User> unpaidUsers =  users.stream()
    .filter(e -> (!paids.stream()
                  .anyMatch(p-> p.getUserName().equals(e.getUserName()))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: use `paids.stream().noneMatch(p-> p.getUserName().equals(e.getUserName())))` instead of `!paids.stream().anyMatch(p-> p.getUserName().equals(e.getUserName())))`, the former is more appropriate and readable for this task.

Comment: Thanks noneMatch worked

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not with your logic rather in the way you add `User` to your input list.

After you add an object, you mutate the same object and add the same reference

```
 users.add(u);
 u.age = "12";
 u.userName = "ABC";
 users.add(u);
```

After executing the above lines your list has the same `User` reference twice (`User` with name `ABC` and age 12).

Change it to

```
User u = new User();
u.age = "12";
u.userName = "XYZ";
users.add(u);
u = new User(); //Create new User object
u.age = "12";
u.userName = "ABC";
users.add(u);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing bug in same code. As per Aomine used noneMatch(..) and it works for me to get desired output